# Are Regular Expressions universal?

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I would like to know if Regular Expressions are Universal for all languages like PHP, Javascript, etc.?

Comment: Can you define "universal" better? Most languages or frameworks have regular expression support, but the same regular expression will not work on all of them on the same way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question is kind of ambiguous to me: You must define what you mean with *Universal*, but here's my answer:

Regular Expressions are used in almost every programming language like PHP, JavaScript, Perl, Awk, Java, C#, etc...

The thing is that **the syntax may vary** a little bit from one language to another, and each language **may implement them in a different way**, and include or not **some particular features** (usually features that allow regex to recognize not only regular languages, but also others like [Context-Free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language) ones)

If you create a new programming language, you can add them regexes feature, but that doesn't mean the syntax will be exactly the same as regexes syntax in .NET, for example. And not only that: The implementation of the engine will surely be different (more/less efficient) than others...

Comment: from what i got to understand is there are different Regular Expressions engine which is adopted by different languages isn't it? as said by James Anderson PHP and python uses PCRE.

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar you could see it like that, but nothing prevents you from implementing your own engine `:)`

Comment: Python does not use PCRE.  PHP does.  And Perl of course has the PCompatiblestREs that can ever exist.

Answer (score 10):

They're not all exactly the same

[Take a look at this list for some of the differences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines)

Answer (score 4):

No.  There are many dialects of regular expressions, though the basic expressions tend to be quite similar.  Also, a useful feature introduced in one dialect is often copied by other dialects.

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions in themselves are a programming construct. So you'll find that the core concepts regarding expressions for pattern matching are basically universal, however each implementation will provide their specific spin on the syntax to go about accomplishing that.

Answer (score 2):

No. But anything *you* are likely to use will support them in some shape or form.

Comment: Even `zsh` at long last!

Answer (score 1):

The bad news is no!

There are many implementations and variations of regexes.

In a standard unix implementation ksh, bash, grep and awk all use slightly different rules. lua has a very limited regex library and Java has a fully functioning lib but with its own quirks.

The good news is that most of the popular scripting (php, python etc.) languages use "pcre" library and as "pcre" stands for "Perl Compatable Regular Expresions" by definition it works the same as perl regular expressions as far as possible. And the pcre library is linkable from to compiled languages (C,C++ etc).

Comment: Python's regexes are very far from Perl's.

Comment: The mechanisms for invoking the re engine are different and the implementation differs (perl uses its own Python builds on 'pcre' so the syntax of the actual expressions is the same, and, 99.8% of the time the same regex will produce the same result.

Comment: Perl supports all Unicode properties; Python supports none. That alone breaks 90% of my regexes. And Python doesn’t support anything Perl has done with regexes over the ten or fifteen years.